# Working with percentages using integer division in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att, integer-division

I am working in Assembly (x86) and I am working with percentages. My problem is the following one:

I have some value `total_sum` that represents 100%.

I calculate `total_sum/100` to get the value that represents 1%:

```
xorl %edx, %edx
movl total_sum, %eax
movl $100, %ecx
divl %ecx
```

Later in my program I use the result of this division to calculate the percentage represented by some other value.

Example calculation done with a calculator (floating point):

> 515 represents 100%, what percentage does 506 represent?
>
> 515/100 = 5.15
> 506/5.15 = 98.25
>
> This means: 506 represents about 98% of 515.

Unfortunately, using assembly language and integer arithmetic the calculation looks like this:

> 515/100 = 5
> 506/5 = 101
>
> This means that 506 represents 101% of 515.

However, I don't want to have results > 100%.

I was trying to use the value in `%edx` from the first division to do some corrections. However, rounding `%eax` (incrementing if `%edx` indicates that the first digit after the decimal point is 5 or more) did not help a lot.

How can I ensure that I don't get values larger than 100%?

Comment: Please include the code that adds up the numbers into total_sum, and include a set of example values. Based on the description, if the values are not too large, you could multiply them by some power of 10, perhaps 10,000 or 1,000,000, then divide appropriately afterwards.

Comment: Need more information about later calculations. In general; divisions cause precision loss, so you want to postpone all divisions until as late as possible - e.g. rather than doing something like `k = total/100` earlier then `a = b*k` later you might be able to do nothing earlier then `a = (b*total)/100` later.

Comment: @Brendan I edited the question because I think I have understood what the OP wants to ask. However, the problem is even worse than you think: The OP performs two divisions (both with precision loss) instead of one multiplication and one division.

Comment: 8086 or  X86? They are not the same

Comment: (506*100) / 515 gives you the result you want.  Integer division doesn't work like continuous real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I edited your question completely because it was not easy to understand it. I hope that I fully understood your question and the question is still asking what you wants to ask.

The problem you describe is actually not an Assembly language problem but it is a problem that is related to any programming language that can do integer arithmetic like C/C++, Java, Pascal and many others.

Therefore I removed the `x86` tag from your question and added the `integer-division` tag.

The following attempt:

> I was trying to use the value in `%edx` from the first division to do some corrections. However, rounding `%eax` ... did not help a lot.

Will not help you. Let's look at the second calculation you perform later on:

> 570/5 = 114
>   570/6 = 95
>   510/5 = 102
>   510/6 = 85

So if the (corrected) result of the first division is 5, the value 510 will be calculated as 102% although 510<515.

And if the (corrected) result of the first division is 6, the value 570 will be calculated as 95% although 570>515.

This means that there is no integer number `one_percent` that represents 1% and that will give you correct results when performing the operation `percentage = number / one_percent`.

The only chance that you have is performing the following calculation **at the end of your program**:

```
percentage = (100 * number) / total_sum
```

Please note that the order of operations **does** nearly always matter when using integer arithmetic. So the following calculation does **not** give the same results as the calculation above:

```
percentage = 100 * (number / total_sum)
```

Using assembly language you can do the first calculation the following way:

```
mov $100, %edx
mov some_number, %eax
mull %edx
  ; Now (edx:eax) contains the 64-bit value (100*some_number)
mov total_sum, %ecx
divl %ecx
  ; Now eax contains the 32-bit value (100*some_number)/total_sum
```